# Input shape for functional Tensorflow api

Tags: python, tensorflow

What would be an example of properly shaped inputs for the following nn?

```
  inputA = Input(shape=(240, 1))
  inputB = Input(shape=(240, 1))

  layerA1 = LSTM(60, return_sequences=True)(inputA)
  layerB1 = LSTM(60, return_sequences=True)(inputB)

  layerA2 = LSTM(60, return_sequences=True)(layerA1)
  layerB2 = LSTM(60, return_sequences=True)(layerB1)

  layerA3 = LSTM(60, return_sequences=False)(layerA2)
  layerB3 = LSTM(60, return_sequences=False)(layerB2)

  x = Concatenate()([layerA3, layerB3])
  output = Dense(5, activation='linear', name='dense')(x)
  model = tf.keras.Model([inputA, inputB], output)

  # What inputs into 
  model.fit(...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This NN expects 2 inputs (a tuple).
The shape of each input should be (N, 240, 1).

For example:

```
x1 = np.random.randn(1000,240,1)
x2 = np.random.randn(1000,240,1)
model.predict((x1, x2))
```

If you want to fit the model. Do this:

```
#first you need to compile
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])  
#then fit
y = np.random.randint(0, 5, (1000))
model.fit((x1, x2), y, epochs=2, batch_size=32)
```